# NullBooleanField is always True

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

Please spare your valuable time and help me.

The idea of my app is that each User will receive a set of the same 30 cards, and then he has to decide each card is Important or Not.

I have 2 classes as follows:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    card_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=False)

    def display(self):
        return self.content

    def __str__(self):
        return "Card  " + str(self.card_number)


class Choice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card)
    is_important = models.NullBooleanField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user','card')

    def get_choices(user):
        return Choice.objects.filter(pk=user.pk)

    def __str__(self):
        return " %s : Card %d : %s" % (self.user.username, self.card.card_number, self.is_important)
```

And in views.py, when user decides the card is important or not :

```
    card_number= request.GET.get('card_number')
    is_important= request.GET.get('is_important')    
    user = request.user

    # assume that user=admin, card_number=1 and is_important is False

    if card_number != None and is_important != None:
        try:
            card = Card.objects.get(card_number=card_number)
            choice= Choice.objects.create(user=user, card=card, is_important=is_important)
            print(choice)  # return admin: Card 1: False 
            print(Choice.objects.get(card__card_number=card_number))  # return admin: Card 1: True
            print(choice)  # return admin: Card 1: False 
        except IntegrityError:
            print("User had done with this Card")
```

I don't understand why:

```
print(choice)  # return admin: Card 1: False
```

but

```
print(Choice.objects.get(card__card_number=1))  # return admin: Card 1: True
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure this is related, but the return statements in your `Choice` model definitions need to be indented another level

Comment: and in the `Meta` declaration

Comment: can you provide an example of a GET request you make?

Comment: Thank you all of you. I have tried the solution of schwobaseggl, and it works like a charm. By the way, the GET request I have is : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/?card=3&choice=False"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_important` is taken from the `GET` `QueryDict` as a (presumably) non-empty string. When you pass such a string as a parameter for a `(Null)BooleanField`, the ORM will cast it to a `bool`, and since non-empty strings evaluate to `True`, that's what gets stored in the db.

Assuming that you pass `'True'`, `'False'` or `'None'` as get parameter for `is_important`, you could do sth like:

```
is_important = request.GET.get('is_important')  # this is a string
is_important = {'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}[is_important]
```

I should maybe add that the instance returned by `.objects.create()` and the instance returned by `.objects.get()` are not necessarily identical even if the `get` call retrieves the db record that was inserted by the `create` call. The former will still have the attributes that were passed as `kwargs` (like the string `'False'`) whereas the latter will have the attributes as retrieved from the database (and thus the value of a `BooleanField` will now be cast to `bool`):

```
choice = Choice.objects.create(user=user, card=card, is_important=is_important)
# choice.is_important = 'False'

choice = Choice.objects.get(user=user, card=card, is_important=is_important)
# choice.is_important = True (= bool('False'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. {'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}[is_important] is such an intelligent way!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to schwobaseggl's answer (another way) you better use Django [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) with `cleaned_data` to prevent those complications.

Comment: Thank you trantu. I don't use Django form because I think it is not necessary for this simple class Choice. Anyway, I will try forms once things get complicated. By the way, your name sounds Vietnamese? I am Vietnamese.

Comment: Hey. Tat nhien roi. MInh la nguoi Viet. Nhin cai ten la biet :) Nice to see you here, my friend :)